# Access private members of local objects (of same class type)

Tags: c++, oop, private-members, local-variables, member-functions

I need to access the private members of a local object from a member function. The example explains it better I think. Is there a way to do this without making *a public, or without providing a function specifically for assigning to *a ? This operator+ function may have to allocate and/or deallocate *a for the local object various times.

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921185/why-do-objects-of-the-same-class-have-access-to-each-others-private-data#answer-6921318) seems to suggest that this should work.

```cpp
// object.h
class object {
    char *a;
    ...
}
// object.cpp
object object::operator+(object const &rhs) const {
    int amount = ...
    object local();

    // this is ok
    this->a = new char[amount];
    // this is ok too
    rhs.a = new char[amount];
    // this is not
    local.a = new char[amount];
    ....
}
```

My compile error (g++ 4.6.3) is:

```
error: request for member ‘a’ in ‘local’, which is of non-class type ‘object()’
```

Comment: Looks like you're trying to call the object constructor, right? You dont need the '()' when calling the default constructor, only when you pass arguments to the constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
object local();
```

is actually a function declaration, not an object definition. Create your variable using:

```
object local;
```

Since `operator +` is a class member, you have the rights to access `private` members, so the issue is due to **most vexing parse**.