# Prevent instances of the same class from calling public functions (C++)

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do objects of the same class have access to each other’s private data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921185/why-do-objects-of-the-same-class-have-access-to-each-others-private-data)

Something I have never understood with trying to keep encapsulation:

Say I have a class called `GameObject`, and a derived class called `Human`. `GameObject` has a private variable `position`. I have multiple instances of `Human`, I want each human to be able to call `SetPos()` and set it's position as it wants. I do not however want one human to have the power to set up the position of another human. This is my problem.

If I have `SetPos` public or protected, each human can alter each others positions, if `SetPos()` is private, a human cannot even set its own position ( I need this, might be a weak example but I hope you understand).

Can anyone offer a solution?

Thanks.

Comment: Unless you're passing in a pointer of another human object, I'm not sure how a human object can alter another object's position.

Comment: @JosephH Probably what he has is pointers to `GameObjects` and what he wants is that, if the `GameObject` is a `Human` he may not call `setPos` on the other `GameObject` that might be a `Human`.

Answer (score 1):

> if SetPos() is private, a human cannot even set its own position

Actually, it can, if `SetPos` is defined on `Human`. A `private` method can only be called from inside the class, but it does not protect instances of the same class from each other:

```
class Human {
  private:
    void set_pos(int i) { std::cout << "moving to " << i << std::endl; }
  public:
    void set_pos_on_other(Human &other, int i) const { other.set_pos(i); }
};

int main()
{
    Human alice, bob;
    bob.set_pos_on_other(alice, 10);
}
```

If `SetPos` is defined on `GameObject` and it has to be called by a `Human`, even if only on itself, then it needs to be `protected` or `public`.

To solve the problem of objects calling each other's `private` methods, you simply need to program carefully and stick to your invariants. C++ offers no special syntax for this. Whenever a `Human` method gets passed a reference or pointer to another `Human`, it can call that `Human`'s `private` methods all it wants.

Comment: I think `SetPos()` is a member of `GameObject`, so if it was private, `Human` could not call it.

Comment: @BjörnPollex: ah, right. My main point still stands, though, I'll try to amend the answer.

Comment: Does it make any sense to have the setter as member in the derived class when the variable itself is member of the base class?

Comment: @moooeeeep: not if the variable is `private`.

Answer (score 1):

Encapsulation with public and private is intended to solve a different problem, namely that of making it easier to code the class by isolating it from other classes. Not isolating individual objects.

Perhaps you can restrict access by managing the pointers? Don't make pointers to objects generally available, but always go through an interface of some sort, identifying which object you want to use by a number or some other key?