# Why does the first statement here not violate protected access while the second one does?

Tags: c++, protected

I am studying this code:

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    A() {};

    void fox(A& otherA) { otherA.hello(); }

protected:
    void hello() {std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;}
};

A a1,a2;

int main(void)
{
    a1.fox(a2);
    a1.hello();
}
```

and am a bit confused as to how saying `a1.fox(a2)` will compile while saying `a1.hello()` will not. I would have assumed it would break because while I can call protected and private functions from within a class...allowing me to do that on the `otherA` object means I would have to be aware that I am calling it from within a member of it's own class. Why/how does this work?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921185/why-do-objects-of-the-same-class-have-access-to-each-others-private-data

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Protected is not instance-by-instance access control, it's a class-by-class access control.

`main()` (which is not in any class) cannot call private or protected methods of any class at all; hence it fails to call `a1.hello()`.

The implementation of `A::fox(A&)`, on the other hand, is inside the class `A`, so it can call its private and protected methods, both on itself and on other instances of the class.

Answer (score 0):

Because `A` is making the call to `otherA.hello();`. You cannot call into it `private` or `protected` code directly, but descendants of `A`, including `A` itself, can call into `A` (descendants cannot access `A`'s `private` data/methods, but `A` can access `A`'s `private` data/methods).  Relatedly, `A` can also access the `private` data/methods of other instances of `A` (this is generally how copy constructors and assignment operators work).

In fact, it's the ability to use `protected` code within the `class` that enables the creation of some very powerful OO concepts. With that said, I see it as an abuse to call an inner-object's `private` or `protected` methods even when possible, but using them directly against yourself is hopefully by design rather than convenience.

In C++, you can provide abstract implementations of `class`es (or `struct`s for that matter) by marking items as `virtual` and not providing an implementation.

```
class A
{
public:
    void set_value(const std::string &value)
    {
        if (is_valid(value))
        {
            this->value = value;
        }
    }

    const std::string &get_value() const
    {
        return value;
    }
protected:
    virtual boolean is_valid(const std::string &value) const = 0;
private:
    std::string value;
}
```

Then

```
class B : public A
{
protected:
    virtual boolean is_valid(const std::string &value) const
    {
        return value != "abc";
    }
}
```

Notice that `A` is setup to inherit functionality, and it is built to anticipate it being supplied (granted the example above doesn't really provide a lot of utility, but it does show what I mean).

Answer (score 0):

The access control in C++ is at class level. Not instance level.

Compiler can't possibly know if `otherA` is actually the same instance or not. You need **runtime support** to actually determine the identity of the instance to provide such access control.

Apart from the performance problem that this presents, the objective of C++ is to catch errors at compile time, not execution time. As stroustrup says, data-encapsulation and type-safety features can't prevent someone from doing fraud (when the program has unmediated access to all allocated memory).

Now, why is it ok to settle for a solution without runtime check. An anology could help - because as an implementor of a class, you won't rob your own house.