# How do i access the private data of an object which is passed by reference to operator= function?

Tags: c++, overloading, private, operator-keyword

I wonder how I am able to access the private data of an object which is passed by reference or value? this code works. Why? i need some explanations.

```
class test_t {
    int data;
public:
    test_t(int val = 1): data(val){}
    test_t& operator=(const test_t &);
};

test_t& test_t::operator=(const test_t & o){
    this->data = o.data;
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: @kiviak Thanks captain obvious.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921185/why-do-objects-of-the-same-class-have-access-to-each-others-private-data

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`private` means that all instances of the `test_t` class can see each other's private data.

If C++ was to be stricter, and to limit `private` access to methods within the same instance, it would be effectively saying that the type of `*this` is "more powerful" than the type of your `o` reference.

The type of `*this` is the same (†) as the type of `o`, i.e. `test_t &`, and therefore `o` can do anything that `*this` can do.

(†) *The same type, apart from the addition of `const`, but that's not important here.*

Comment: To put it semantically, `private` means that it's part of the implementation of the class and can only be accessed by the implementation of the class.