# Why this code is working ? I mean the member is private

Tags: c++

why this code is working? I mean the `value` is a private variable, why function `assign()` can access it directly?

```
class A {
private:
    int value;
public:
    A() :value(0){ }
    void assign(A x)
    {
        value = x.value;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    A b;
    a.assign(b);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Class methods can access private members of their own class. Private just means it can't be directly accessed from outside of the class. It would be rather useless if private meant "this can't be used by anybody".

Comment: your introductory book/class/tutorial surely explains the access modifiers.

Comment: And with recent edit, this aspect of the question is clear now.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to call the method, now I add it to the code, and it still working. I cannot understand it clearly. @Yunnosch

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do objects of the same class have access to each other's private data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921185/why-do-objects-of-the-same-class-have-access-to-each-others-private-data)

Comment: After the intended improvement of question was achieved, I deleted my corresponding comment, in order to not confuse anybody, now that the question has been edited by OP.

Comment: @HostileFork Yes, This is exactly what I want to know. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

The `private` keyword means that no code *outside the class* can access the class.

Methods of the same class can access it, sure, because if they couldn't nobody could access private variables and they'd be useless.

If you worry about the access from the method called for `A` to the private member of `B`, don't worry.
The idea of `private` and `public` is making the implementation details of the class a thing nobody knows (and needs to know), but the class itself.
The class `A` "knows" how `A` itself is implemented, and so is "allowed" to use it's internals - `private`s, even if they're not of the called object.

Answer (score 2):

Member functions (e.g., A::assign(A)) can access private members of their respective class, in addition to protected members of inherited classes.

Answer (score 2):

`int value` is `private`, but `void assign(A x)` is `public`. In main function (outside class A) you can access only to `public` methods. Inside class A (for example in `assign` method) you can access to `public`, `private` and `protected` members

For example:
You can't write something like this:

```
A obj;
obj.value;
```

because `value` is private.
But you can access it using other methods: for example you can define `set(int val)` method

```
class A {
private:
    int value;
public:
    A() :value(0){ }
    void set(int val) 
    { 
        value = val; 
    }
    void assign(A x)
    {
        value = x.value;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A obj;
    obj.set(10);
}
```