# How to set two separate instances of a class equal to each other c++

Tags: c++

I understand that, for classes, private members can only be accessed by public members. But does that apply for each discrete instance of a class or can the public member of one instance directly access the private member of another instance.

For example, say there are two instances of class: `instance1` and `instance2`. And say that the class has a private member `x` and public members `getX()` and `setX()`. If I want to set `instance1.x` equal to `instance2.x` which if the following would be correct:

```
instance1.setX(instance2.x)
```

Or

```
instance1.setX(instance2.getX())
```

Comment: Which is correct (I assume you mean "will compile") depends on the scope where it's supposed to appear.

Comment: _"or can the public member of one instance directly access the private member of another instance"_? Sure. Otherwise, e.g., default copy constructor wouldn't be allowed to copy-construct private members.

Comment: First one is not allowed as `x` is private. You can't directly access `x` from object. Thus, you are left with second option only.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do objects of the same class have access to each other's private data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921185/why-do-objects-of-the-same-class-have-access-to-each-others-private-data)

Answer (score 4):

An instance of a class can see the private members of another instance of the same class.

An instance of a class cannot see the private members of another instance of a different class.

An instance of a class can see the public members of another instance of a different class.

When we say "can see", we mean that the members are in scope for the implementation of the class method.

```
class A
{
public:
    Foo() { x = 10; }                  // is legal
    Bar(A & another) {another.x = 12;} // is legal
private:
    int x;
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    A b;

    a.Bar(b);  // Is legal

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside code of that class member functions or its friends you can use

```
instance1.setX(instance2.x);
instance1.x = instance2.x;
this->x = instance2.x;
x = instance2.x;
```

Otherwise, you need to write

```
instance1.setX(instance2.getX());
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, think about where you call `instance1.setX()`. Let's say you call it in some function `foo()`:

```
void foo() {
    ...

    instance1.setX(instance2.x);

    ...
}
```

If `foo()` is not a member nor [`friend`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend) of your `Instance` class, then it can't access `instance2.x`; you'd have to use a getter here: `instance2.getX()`.

Otherwise, you can use either method: `instance2.x` or `instance2.getX()`.