# are copy and move constructors automatic friends?

Tags: c++, friend-class

We can access private variables of another class when we define copy or move constructors. Does C++ make them `friend` to each other automatically?

For example:

```
my_str::my_str(my_str&& m) 
{
    size_ = m.size_; //accessing private variable another my_str class
    buff_ = m.buff_; //accessing private variable another my_str class
    m.buff_ = nullptr;
    m.size_ = 0;
}
```

Comment: This is the very same class. So ne friend is needed.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921185/why-do-objects-of-the-same-class-have-access-to-each-others-private-data - in short, access control in C++ does not discern between object _instances_, only between different types.

Comment: When you write "another my_str class" it's a straight-up mistake. It's another my_str _instance_, and other comments and answers explain what that entails

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It is not considered friend, but yes, any member function of class `my_str` can access private members of all instances of type `my_str`, not just the `this` instance:

```
class my_str {
    void foo(my_str& other) {
        // can access private members of both this-> and other.
    }

    static void bar(my_str& other) {
        // can access private members of other.
    }
};
```

The general idea behind it is to allow 2 or more objects of the same type to interact without having to expose their private members.

Answer (score 10):

Member functions of the class itself always have access to the `private` members, no matter whether the member function is defined in-class or out-of-class and no matter whether it is a special member function such as a copy/move constructor.

Therefore they are not `friend` of the class, because that doesn't make any sense. They are already part of the class. Still, they have access to all `private` members, not because they are `friend`s, but because they are part of the class.

If it wasn't possible to initialized members in a constructor (because they are inaccessible), then the whole concept of member accessibility would be pointless. (How would you initialize the member?)

---

Also, accessibility is not in any way a matter of the object on which a member is accessed. Accessibility is a matter only of where in the code a name (the name of the member) is used. If a function can access the member of one instance of a class, then it can also access the member of another instance of the same class.